# Hard Disk laggy

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Hey guys I am considering to purchase a new HDD after a series of events that happened : 
Couple days ago my PC froze while I was playing a game, I wasn't able to close any processes with my Task Manager and I decided to RR the pc. After I did that my pc went to boot and immediately after I got the "Attempting to repair the disk %", it failed. Tried to recover it but unfortunately I wasn't able to get past the (windows couldn't start normally). I decided to reinstall my Windows and I went for a clean install, deleted the partitions, BUT when I tried to format my whole partition I got this : "Windows couldn't not format a partition on disk0 : error code 0x80070057". Tried to format it with diskpart but without success, managed a day later to install my windows(normally). Yesterday I had another freeze/lag during a game, and I've seen that the computer lags terribly...
Did some checkups :

Samsung HD105SI

1) SMART returned to me with healthy and only one warning at my Interface CRC error count
Current : 69 , Worst : 1 , Threshold : 0,  Data : 16887
2) Tested the read speed ( HD tune pro) : 
minimum speed : 0.2MB
maximum: 105,5 MB
average: 65 MB

acc time : 20 ms
burst rate 159 mb/s

Is my hard drive beyond salvation ?  As far as I know there's no way to fix a HDD problem but with a replacement.
Thanks and sorry for the long post

Comment: I would suggest getting liveUSB with MHDD on it so you can do full HDD scan and see if the HDD is dying.

Comment: Coming back with an answer asap.

Comment: @ExtremeSwat: You might want to check that the SATA data cable is plugged in firmly at both ends as a bad connection can cause CRC errors. Or even better, try a new cable as it is possible the current one is defective.

Comment: @James, I've gotten that error previously and I did change the cables. The error remained even after both cable changes ( power supply and sata )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the other comments, did you perform a chkdsk X: /r ?

Sometimes your ear is better than SMART, try to listen close to the disk when it's on load if it is making strange noises.

Comment: It was making weird sounds.
Anyways I've bought a new drive, I was supposed to make an upgrade to Sata 3 anyways. Thanks